# error:bad operand type for binary operation &&

Tags: bluej

Here's the code

```
import java.io.*;
class WORD2
 {  
public void main() throws IOException
{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
        String str=br.readLine().toUpperCase()+" ";
        int l=str.length();
        String word="";
        int p=0;
        String word2[]=new String[l];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            char ch=str.charAt(i);
            **if((str.charAt(i))&&(str.charAt(i+1)!= ' '))**// THE ERROR COMES IN THIS STATEMNET SHOWING THE ERROR
            {
                if(ch!=' ')
                {
                    word=word+ch;   //TAKING EACH WORD
                }
                else 
                {
                    word2[p++]=word;  //STORING EACH WORD
                    word="";
                }

        }}
        String q="";
            for(int k=0;k<p;k++)
            {
                q=q+word2[k]+" ";
            }
            System.out.print("q="+q);
        }}
```

**Its a program to remove the unnecessary blank space between the words in a sentence.**

Answer (score 0):

```
if((str.charAt(i)!= ' ' )&&(str.charAt(i+1)!= ' '))
```

is the correct syntax, since IF requires bool (true/false) to consider.
As you have it the first part returns char.
Also, make a check at str.charAt(i+1) else you will get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException!